# Ratio estimator in sampling

Tags: self-study, sampling, sample, ratio

> Let the population $U=(1,2,3)$. We want to estimate
> $R=\frac{\mu_y}{\mu_x}$.Consider the estimators
> $$\hat{R_1}=\frac{\overline{y}}{\overline{x}},\hat{R_2}=\frac{\overline{y}}{\mu_x}$$
> where $Y=(9,42,53)$ and $X=(1,4,5)$.
>
> Find the distributions of the estimators and their bias. Consider the sample size $n=2$

Considering a simple random sample without replacement, we have that $S=[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]$

$$\begin{bmatrix}s:&12&13&23\\\hat{R_1}: &10.2&10.33&10.55\\ p:&1/3&1/3&1/3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Just to ilustrate, taking $s=(1,2)$ I did
$$\frac{\overline{y}}{\overline{x}}=\frac{(\frac{9+42}{2})}{(\frac{1+4}{2})}=10.2$$

but solutions say that the distribution is

$$\begin{bmatrix}s:&12&13&23\\\hat{R_1}: &0.098&0.097&0.095\\ p:&1/3&1/3&1/3 \end{bmatrix}$$

It is as if they had done $$\hat{R_1}=\frac{\overline{x}}{\overline{y}}$$

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Pages 206++ in Leslie Kish' book *Survey Sampling* has an excellent discussion of ratio estimators.

Comment: The Solutions inverted y and x; choose whether you want to do the same.  And in a sampling text, you must pay attention to notation.  $\overline{x}$ refers to the sample mean, whereas $\overline{X}$ refers to a population mean.

Comment: @SteveSamuels both solutions are right?  What is the difference?  You know some book with solutions for this topic for self-study?

Comment: I haven't offered you a solution, just an observation.  Whether to use x/y or y/x depends on the problem. Another  book good for learning  is Sampling of Populations by Levy and Lemeshow.

Comment: I'ld just say that if your instructor used the x/y form, solve that and note that the Solutions got it reversed..  The Levy & Lemeshow book has other examples like that in the question.